# Controller action result method being called multi times if static image is not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working in mvc project and I am new to MVC. I am facing one issue, like Controller method "Detail" is called first time when we request for page after if any static image is not found then also called. like below image. Do you know why this is happening in MVC? How to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MVC is basically matching image URL to the Detail method. Put all your static files into Content directory. This way requests for images won't match your MVC routes:

/details/Cream-Cotton
 /Content/details/images/search_icon.png